# Filter table with Json array column by integer value

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, npgsql, ef-core-3.1

In EF Core how can I efficiently check if text column of Json array contains any number from passed integer array using LINQ?

Example of table, where `Id` is `integer` type and `Name` and `TypeJson` are `text`

```
| Id  | Name       | TypeJson |
| --- | ---------- | -------- |
| 1   | Name One   | [1,2]    |
| 2   | Name Two   | [2,3]    |
| 3   | Name Three | [4,7]    |
```

In Postgresql I would have written something like this

```
SELECT *
FROM "Table"
WHERE translate("TypeJson", '[]','{}')::int[] && ARRAY[1, 7]
```

where the select would return 1 and 3 rows.
I'd like to achieve same result by using LINQ functions.
I tried using `EF.Functions` but didn't achieve much. My attempt

```
await _dbContect.Table
.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.TypeJson ) && 
            EF.Functions.JsonContains(x.TypeJson , "[1]")
.ToListAsync();
```

But it produces error as column is type of text and not Json

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The EF JSON methods require a JSON parameter and none was found.
```

The entity:

```
public class Table
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string TypeJson { get; set; }
}
```

Using `FromSqlRaw()` is not possible because there is already written code and would be preferable if I didn't have to rewrite whole code block.

Comment: Can you please share the entity setup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I found out my code had three main problems

```
await _dbContect.Table
    .Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.TypeJson) && 
                EF.Functions.JsonContains(x.TypeJson , "[1]")
    .ToListAsync();
```

1. First of all I was using `EF.Functions.JsonContains()` function on
   text column which is not valid, json functions are deliberately
   written for `jsonb` type.
2. After altering column type to `jsonb`, the
   second problem was using string function to check if `jsonb` column
   was null or empty which doesn't make sense and produces exception. [Link to github issue](https://github.com/npgsql/efcore.pg/issues/2592)
3. The third problem was the parameter I tried to filter with `"[1]"`, integer needs to be passed as a JsonElement `JsonSerializer.SerializeToElement(value);` [Link to github issue by ahanusa](https://github.com/npgsql/efcore.pg/issues/2363)

Credits to @GuruStron for directing me to correct direction

Comment: Glad you have resolved the issue!